# Interbase how to add guid field to existing table

Tags: sql, interbase

I have an old existing interbase table and I want to add a primary key field to and populate it.  Is there any way to do it all in the SQL statement (like SQL server).  Example:

```
ALTER TABLE IBUSERS ADD IBUSERSPK VARCHAR(32) default (newid()) NOT NULL
```

As far as I can tell in interbase newid function does not exist unless I am missing something.

I am using IBExpert and also have IBConsole.

Or am I stuck with populating this field in code after it gets created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears interbase has no easy way to SQL populate a guid field.  Therefore the solution is to create your own UDF function in the database to create a random guid.  It then becomes a three step process:

Add the field to the table

```
ALTER TABLE IBUSERS ADD IBUSERSPK  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
```

Populate the new field using the UDF:

```
UPDATE IBUSERS SET IBUSERSPK = GETGUID()
```

Add primary key constraint if it is such:

```
ALTER TABLE  IBUSERS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_IBUSERS PRIMARY KEY (IBUSERSPK)
```

The nice thing about this is that then this function can be used anytime/anywhere in the database.

Comment: I hope that helps someone because there really is not much Google type support for Interbase.